# RXJS Marble Testing TestScheduler not flushing observable and wrong expectation for Angular Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine, angular-test, rxjs-marbles

I am trying to learn how to rxjs marble test using testScheduler. When trying to test a behavior subject getter and setter I get the error `Expected spy setVersatilityRowOptions to have been called with:[ VersatilityHeaderRowOptions({ onlyShowCertifiedOperators: true, showOffTeamOperators: false })] but it was never called.`

Here is what my code looks like

My Service Functions

```js
setVersatilityRowOptions(versatilityRowOptions: VersatilityHeaderRowOptions): void {
  this._versatilityRowOptions.next(versatilityRowOptions);
}

getVersatilityRowOptions(): Observable<VersatilityHeaderRowOptions> {
  return this.$versatilityRowOptions;
}
```

My Component Function I'm testing

```js
updateVersatility(): void {
  this.versatilityApiService.getVersatilityRowOptions()
    .subscribe(versatilityRowOptions => {
        this.versatilityApiService.setVersatilityRowOptions(versatilityRowOptions);
  });
}
```

My Test File (I have mocked the object, the service, and the services functions in my spec file as well. Additionally, the service has been correctly injected into my spec file).

```js
const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
});

describe('updateVersatility()', () => {
  it('should update behavior subject', () => {
    testScheduler.run(({cold}) => {
      const source1$ = cold('--(x|)', {x: mockVersatilityHeaderRowOptions});  
    spyOn(component['versatilityApiService'],'getVersatilityRowOptions')
      .and.returnValue(source1$);
    spyOn(component['versatilityApiService'], 'setVersatilityRowOptions');

    component.updateVersatility();

    getTestScheduler().flush();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component['versatilityApiService'].getVersatilityRowOptions)
      .toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component['versatilityApiService'].setVersatilityRowOptions)
      .toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockVersatilityHeaderRowOptions);

});
```

I tried to run the test Scheduler and thought that the observable would flush and I could expect the setter to be called but it was not.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it is similar to my case where a component subscribes to a RxJS observable. I also use NgRx Store and the observable is coming from it, so my solution here possibly doesn't exactly apply to your case, but hoping it does.

My solution uses `TestScheduler.schedule` from `jasmine-marbles` and `fakeAsync` from `@angular/core/testing`.

```js
  it('should varify after observables emit', fakeAsync(() => { // <--
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // make the observables in the component emit values

    getTestScheduler().schedule(() => { // <--
      fixture.detectChanges();

      // verify things about the component
      expect(component['someService'].setSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
    ), time('|')); // <--
  });
```

Hopefully, it could also help in your case.